# Build and Install clRNG

Tags: opencl

For a project i need Random Numbers in an OpenCL Kernel. I found the clRNG library which is exactly what i need.

https://github.com/clMathLibraries/clRNG

But i have some trouble with installing it. I follows the Installation intructions on Github for the install with VisualStudio. I comiled the files with Cmake and got a clRNG.sln File. I can open this file with visual studio but i dont know whats the next step.

It would be great if someone could give me a detaild step-by-step guide for installing the library.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you figured this out by yourself already, but here is the guide anyhow:

1. Build the *ALL_BUILD* project, either by going to *Build -> Build Solution* or right-clicking *ALL_BUILD* in the Solution Explorer and selecting *Build*.
2. Build the *INSTALL* project under CMakePredefinedTargets in the Solution Explorer by right-clicking on it and selecting *Build*.
3. Now all the needed files should be in the *package* folder inside the solution folder.

To use the library in a VS project, you need to the project properties and adding the clRNG *include* folder in the project Include Directories and the *lib/import* folder in the project Library Directories. You can find the settings by going to the project properties and selecting *Configuration Properties -> VC++ Directories*.